# Persisting an array list of Integers in Hibernate throws an exception

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application (Primefaces+Hibernate+Oracle DB) I'm trying to persist an entity that has an array list of Integers (manageesIds) to two tables (the arraylist will go into the "details" table).

It throws a ClassCastException when trying to save the entity using the web application. However, it works fine when I call the "updateJobDescription" method from a main method rather than from the web application.

Entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP_JOB_DESCRIPTION")
public class EmployeeInfo
{
public EmployeeInfo()
{
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
    manageesIds.add(new Integer(1));
}

@Id
@Column(name = "emp_no")
private Integer empNo;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

public String getOfficialPosition()
{
    return officialPosition;
}

public void setOfficialPosition(String officialPosition)
{
    this.officialPosition = officialPosition;
}

@Column(name = "emp_national_id_no")
private String nationalIdNo;

@Column(name = "emp_jawal_phone")
private String mobile;

@Column(name = "emp_phone_ext")
private String extension;

@Column(name = "emp_onreal_job_type")
private Integer actualPositionId;

@Column(name = "emp_st_old_dest")
private Integer workDestination;

@Column(name = "emp_city")
private Integer cityId;

@Column(name = "emp_specialty_desc")
private String specialtyDesc;

@Column(name = "emp_duties_desc")
private String dutiesDesc;

@Column(name = "emp_mng_job_desc")
private Integer managerPositionId;

@Column(name = "emp_qualification")
private Integer qualificationId;

@Column(name = "emp_last_qualification")
private Integer lastQualificationId;

@Column(name = "emp_experience")
private String experience;

@Column(name = "emp_training")
private String training;

@Transient
private String name;
@Transient
private String email;
@Transient
private String officialPosition;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "emp_job_description_detail", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_NO"))
@Column(name = "EMP_MNG_CHAIRED_JOB_DESC")
private List<Integer> manageesIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Save method:

```
    public static synchronized void updateJobDescription(EmployeeInfo jobDesc)
{
    Session session = getNewSession(true);

    session.saveOrUpdate(jobDesc);

    closeSession(session, true);
}
```

Exception:

```
14:42:26,586 SEVERE [javax.faces.event] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8888-3) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:305)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:57)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:811)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1201)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:279)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1181)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:379)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at com.kku.jd.persistence.PersistenceManager.closeSession(PersistenceManager.java:53)
at com.kku.jd.persistence.PersistenceManager.updateJobDescription(PersistenceManager.java:137)
at com.kku.jd.managedbeans.UpdateBean.updateJobDescription(UpdateBean.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at com.kku.jd.filter.InitializeSessionFilter.doFilter(InitializeSessionFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Update:**

Here is how I call it from the Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EmployeeInfo empInfo = new EmployeeInfo();

    empInfo.setEmail("sary@gmail.com");
    empInfo.setEmpNo(7);
    empInfo.setMobile("5698535");
    empInfo.setName("Sary");
    empInfo.setOfficialPosition("Dev Manager");

    empInfo.setNationalIdNo("123456789");

    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ids.add(1);
    empInfo.setManageesIds(ids);
    updateJobDescription(empInfo);

}
```

As for the web app, a command button invokes a managed bean's method.

Commnad button in xhtml file:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.fourth_save}" ajax="false" actionListener="#{updateBean.updateJobDescription}" />
```

Managed bean:

```
public void updateJobDescription()
{
    // save all entered info
    PersistenceManager.updateJobDescription(empInfo);

    // return navigation to first page
    wizard.setStep(FIRST_STEP);

}
```

Comment: How do you call it from the main method and how from the web app?

Comment: @user1983983 Question updated to include method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if you bind `manageesIds` to an [`UISelectMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html) based component like `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` or `<h:selectManyListbox>` without explicitly specifying a converter which converts the submitted `String` value to an `Integer`. You've there namely a `List<Integer>` property and the generic type is absent during runtime (that moment when EL runs) and thus all EL sees is a simple `List`. As long as you don't explicitly specify a converter, EL will assume that it's under the covers just a `List<String>`.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Explicitly specify the converter. You can use the JSF builtin `IntegerConverter` for this:

   ```
   <h:selectManyCheckbox ... converter="javax.faces.Integer">
   ```
2. Use a typed array instead of a generic list as property. This way JSF/EL will be able to determine the concrete type and apply automatic coercion/conversion.

   ```
   private Integer[] manageesIds;
   ```

Comment: I'm finally honored with an answer from @BalusC :) and as usual a correct one.
By the way, I'm using a <p:selectOneMenu> which is a UISelectOne (not UISelectMany) based component.
I know you're asked this question a lot, but how do you manage to dig deep to find these kind of answers?

Comment: You're welcome. I just recognized the symptoms. It's by the way strange to bind a `List<Integer>` as `UISelectOne` value which can take only one item directly. In any way, glad I could help.

Comment: Actually I had several `<p:selectOneMenu>` components in my screen. Each of them is binded to a different element in the `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Ah right, by index like so `#{bean.manageesIds[0]}`? Yes, then you still indeed need a converter.

Comment: Exactly. Yes, a converter fixes the problem. Thanks.